# prove the definite Integral

Tags: numerical-methods, gamma-function, elliptic-integrals

Hey is anyone here who can prove that:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{2\sin(x)} dx = \frac{2\Gamma(\frac{3}{4})^2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$

we haven't had the Gamma Function in our lectures. But i just want prove that my Integral Apporximation is near the real Value.

Comment: What is the point of $\sqrt{2}$ being inside the integral?

Comment: Welcome. Do you want a proof of the integral identity or a “proof” that your “approximation” is good? You should show what your approximation is!

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_to_the_gamma_function), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Other_identities_and_formulas) & [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula#Known_formulae).

Comment: my Approximation is 1,70216. So its near the value of the Term above(1.69443). So its more a proof of the Integral Identity.

Comment: Did you get the Gamma function formula from some online solver?  If not, where is this formula from?  For proving this identity, do you know complex analysis?  Or would you want an entirely real derivation?

Comment: Yes. I got it from online source. So i thought there is way to solve this if an online calculator can do it

Answer (score 4):

$$B(x,y)=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{2x-1}(t)\cos^{2y-1}(t)dt=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)} \implies \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{2\sin(t)}dt=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}B(3/4,1/2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\frac{\Gamma(3/4)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(5/4)}=\frac{4\pi^{3/2}}{\Gamma(1/4)^2}$$
That is equal to your result

Answer (score 0):

An integral approximation method and gamma function in R confirm that the two expressions are equal to at least several significant figures, if not identical.

```
 #Run in R version 4.2.1
 options(digits = 22)
 fn = function(x){ sqrt(2*sin(x))}
 integrate(fn, 0, pi/2, rel.tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.75)
 # 1.694426169587958108664 with absolute error < 1.2e-12
 2*gamma(3/4)**2/sqrt(pi)
 # 1.694426169587958330709
```